Python client for YellowStone Geyser Plugin (gRPC)
I have a Solana RPC node with Yellowstone Geyser plugin and I'm trying to use the Python client to subscribe to transactions, here is my code:
import grpc
from geyser_pb2 import SubscribeRequest, SubscribeRequestFilterAccounts, GetSlotRequest, CommitmentLevel
from geyser_pb2_grpc import GeyserStub


with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:10000') as channel:
    stub = GeyserStub(channel)
    request = SubscribeRequest(
        accounts={
            "PUMP_FUN": SubscribeRequestFilterAccounts(
                account=["6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P"]
            )
        },
        commitment=CommitmentLevel.PROCESSED
    )
    response_stream = stub.Subscribe(iter([request]))
    try:
        for response in response_stream:
            print(f"Received update : {response}")
    except grpc.RpcError as e:
        print(f"RPC error occurred: {e}")


I only get ping messages, not actual transactions (even with an empty SubscribeRequest with no filters). I managed to run the JS example as it has the ready code for this but I'm struggling to do the same with Python.
Am I doing something wrong ?

I received the same response where I would just get pings back.  However if I just let it run, sometimes for over an hour I would eventually get the response I was expecting.  It has taken anywhere from 45 seconds to 2 hours to get that response.
I assume the delay in receiving a response is due to the specs of the test machine but that is still unclear.
